# RequireJS: Module name __ has not been loaded yet for context, but only for SOME, not all

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, js-amd

Now I know this question has been asked a million times before, but I still couldn't figure it out.

I have a huge amount of "defines" in various files. Most the time, this works, but a few of my modules are **"not loaded for context"** sometimes, **even-though I put their names in the "define" statement**.

===========================

## Current Code

index.js (Simplified for StackOverflow)

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '',
    paths: { 
    //TOOLS
        jquery: '../libraries/jquery-1.10.2.min',
        socketio:'socket.io/socket.io',
        jqueryLightBox:'../libraries/jquery.lightbox_me',
        jqueryMigrate:'../libraries/jquery-migrate-1.2.1',
        jqueryUI:'../libraries/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min',
        spinner:'../libraries/jquery.spin',
        jQueryFormPlugin:'../libraries/jquery.form.min',
        jQueryCookiePlugin:'../libraries/jquery.cookie',
        json2:'../libraries/json2', 
        raphael:'../libraries/raphael-min', 
        raphaelPanZoom:'../libraries/raphael.pan-zoom.min',
        bootstrap: '../libraries/bootstrap.min',
        browserDetection: '../libraries/BrowserDetect',
        qtip: '../libraries/jquery.qtip.min',
        imagesloaded: '../libraries/imagesloaded.pkgd.min', 
        eventie: '../libraries/eventie',
        eventEmitter: '../libraries/EventEmitter.min',
        underscore: '../libraries/underscore-min',
        underscoreString: '../libraries/underscore.string.min',
        stacktrace: '../libraries/stacktrace',
        elapseMeMin: '../libraries/elapseMe.min',
        jqueryKeithWood: '../libraries/jquery.svg.min', 
        domReady: '../libraries/domReady',
    //PAGES: (Simplified for StackOverflow)
        TestView: '../javascripts/tests/TestView',
        TestModel: '../javascripts/tests/TestModel',
        TestController: '../javascripts/tests/TestController',
        TestPanelView: '../javascripts/tests/Test-StartPanelView',
        SocketLogic: '../javascripts/SocketLogic',
        Logger: '../javascripts/Logger',

    }, 
    shim: {
    'socketio': {
      exports: 'io'
                },
     'spinner': {
      exports: 'Spinner',
      deps: ['jquery']
                },
    'raphael':  {
     exports: 'Raphael',
      deps: ['jquery']
                },
    'raphaelPanZoom': {
      deps: ['raphael']
            },
    'bootstrap': {},
    'browserDetection':  {
      exports: 'BrowserDetect'
            },
    'underscore': {
      exports: '_'
                },
    'underscoreString': {
      deps: ['underscore'],
      exports: '_'
        },
     'stacktrace': {
      exports: 'printStackTrace'
        },
     'elapseMeMin': {
         exports: 'elapseMe',
         deps: ['jquery']
        }

    }
});

//////////////////
//1) Everything starts with this method. Will execute when the DOM is ready.
/////////////////

require(['domReady'], function (domReady) {
  domReady(function () {
    //This function is called once the DOM is ready.
    //It will be safe to query the DOM and manipulate
    //DOM nodes in this function.
    //Start Loading!
    require(['TestController'], function(TestController)
    {
        TestController.firstMethod();
    }); 
  });
});
```

**TestController.js** (Simplified for StackOverflow)

```
define(['TestModel', 'TestView', 'SocketLogic', 'Logger', 'TestPanelView'], 
function (TestModel, TestView, socketLogic, Logger, TestPanelView) 
{
 return {
    firstMethod: function()
    {
             TestModel.doSomething();
             TestView.doSomethingElse();
             socketLogic.andAnother();
             Logger.log("hi");
             TestPanelView.updateSomething();
             this.anotherMethod();
    },
    anotherMethod: function()
    {
             console.log("hello");
    }
    }
});
```

===========================

## Problem

But, once in a while, I'll randomly get *just one of them* to **"not be loaded for context"**, eventhough the rest were just fine:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "TestPanelView" has not been loaded yet for context: _
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
```

===========================

## Current Fixes

### Fix #1 - Using require('');

Instead of

```
TestPanelView.updateSomething();
```

I have been doing:

```
var testPanelView = require('TestPanelView');
testPanelView.updateSomething();
```

Which *works*, BUT.. **shouldn't it have *already* been loaded into context** since I put it in the header? Why this one? It's the same as all the others!

### Fix #2 - Using require([''],function(){});

This also works, but again I'm just doing this one by one and it feels wrong!

Instead of

```
TestPanelView.updateSomething();
```

Sometimes I do this:

```
require(['TestPanelView'], function(testPanelView){
      testPanelView.updateSomething();
});
```

### Failed Attempts #1

**TestController.js** (Simplified for StackOverflow)

```
define(['require', 'TestModel', 'TestView', 'SocketLogic', 'Logger', 'TestPanelView'], 
function (require) 
{
var TestModel = require('TestModel')
var TestView = require('TestView');
var SocketLogic = require('SocketLogic');
var Logger = require('Logger');
var TestPanelView = require('TestPanelView');
 return {
    firstMethod: function()
    {
             TestModel.doSomething();
             TestView.doSomethingElse();
             SocketLogic.andAnother();
             Logger.log("hi");
             TestPanelView.updateSomething();
             this.anotherMethod();
    },
    anotherMethod: function()
    {
             console.log("hello");
    }
    }
});
```

Here I get the **"not loaded for context"** error again, but this time for all of them.

===========================

## Ideas?

I've been manually patching each one that I find like this, which is **not happening to all**, **only some here and there**, which feels like monkey patching... I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong here :( Anyone know?

Note: I'm using RequireJS v.2.1.10

Comment: There's nothing in the code shown in the question which explains why you'd get "... has not been loaded yet for context". I've read the code of RequireJS and see that the only kind of situation in which this error is raised is if a call like ``var foo = require("...")`` (that is, a ``require`` call with a single string argument) occurs before the module required is loaded.

Comment: huh. Well that's lame :( I always make sure to have the module in the header if I'm using `require("blah")` in the code, I've double and triple checked all my files :( idk what it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to failed attempt #1

```
define(['require', 'TestModel', 'TestView', 'SocketLogic', 'Logger', 'TestPanelView'], 
function (require, testModel, testView, socketLogic, logger, testPanelView) {
    var firstMethod = function() {
             testModel.doSomething();
             testView.doSomethingElse();
             socketLogic.andAnother();
             logger.log("hi");
             testPanelView.updateSomething();
             this.anotherMethod();
    };
    var anotherMethod = function(){
        console.log("hello");
    }
 return {
    firstMethod: firstMethod,
    anotherMethod: anotherMethod
});
```

And don't forget, the opening curly bracket must come after the ending round bracket of the function in the same line.

Comment: This has thrown me for a loop. I had my module structured such that it was returning an object with some function props on it, but the functions were anonymous ones defined in the object literal in the return statement. A required module was consistently `undefined` in one of these functions. Moving the function definitions outside of the returned object literal seems to have fixed it...